# Update to existing iPhone app will not overwrite the settings from Root.plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, plist

I have updated a string value in Root.plist in my source code.

When the app gets updated, I need this new string value to be updated in the app settings.

For some reason, the app settings do not get updated when the app already exists on the device.  If I uninstall the app, and then re-install, the new settings are reflected correctly.

How can I ensure the new settings from Root.plist are reflected in the app settings when updating the app?  Without requiring the user to uninstall/reinstall the app?